# MapReduce implementation in Scala

Tags: scala, frameworks, google-analytics, mapreduce

I'd like to find out good and robust MapReduce framework, to be utilized from Scala.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To add to the answer on Hadoop: there are at least two Scala wrappers that make working with Hadoop more palatable.

Scala Map Reduce (SMR): http://scala-blogs.org/2008/09/scalable-language-and-scalable.html

SHadoop: http://jonhnny-weslley.blogspot.com/2008/05/shadoop.html

**UPD 5 oct. 11**

There is also [Scoobi](https://github.com/NICTA/scoobi) framework, that has awesome expressiveness.

Comment: SHadoop is quite old--it uses the old MR framework.  I updated the implicits at some point: https://github.com/schmmd/Hadoop-Scala-Commons

Answer (score 3):

http://hadoop.apache.org/ is language agnostic.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't ask for Java implementation.  Indeed, Hadoop can be plugged into Scala but the boilerplate code have to be written in Java.

Comment: Write a ScalaHadoopAdapter which takes care of all the boilerplate and publish it as free/open-source?

Comment: the boilerplate does not need to be written in java.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I've become a big fan of Spark

http://spark-project.org/

You have the ability to do in-memory cluster computing, significantly reducing the overhead you would experience from disk-intensive mapreduce operations.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [scouchdb](http://code.google.com/p/scouchdb/), a Scala interface to using [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Another idea is to use [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/).  [ScalaDudes](http://scaladudes.com/node/14) have an example of using GridGain with Scala.  And [here](http://www.jroller.com/nivanov/entry/mapreduce_with_scala_and_gridgain) is another example.

Answer (score 2):

A while back, I ran into exactly this problem and ended up writing a little infrastructure to make it easy to use Hadoop from Scala.  I used it on my own for a while, but I finally got around to putting it on the web.  It's named (very originally) [ScalaHadoop](http://programmer-land.blogspot.com/2010/07/scalahadoop.html).

Answer (score 2):

For a scala API on top of hadoop check out [Scoobi](http://github.com/NICTA/scoobi), it is still in heavy development but shows a lot of promise. There is also some effort to implement distributed collections on top of hadoop in the [Scala incubator](http://github.com/scala-incubator/distributed-collections), but that effort is not usable yet.

There is also a new scala wrapper for cascading from Twitter, called [Scalding](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/scalding).
After looking very briefly over the documentation for Scalding it seems
that while it makes the integration with cascading smoother it still does
not solve what I see as the main problem with cascading: type safety.
Every operation in cascading operates on cascading's tuples (basically a
list of field values with or without a separate schema), which means that
type errors, I.e. Joining a key as a String and key as a Long leads
to run-time failures.

Comment: Scalding does have a type-safe API: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Type-safe-api-reference and in the Fields API (which you are mentioning), joining a string to a long doesn't cause run-time exceptions (if they are both numbers). Of course, in the type-safe API such a join is prohibited by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

to further jshen's point:

hadoop streaming simply uses sockets. using unix streams, your code (any language) simply has to be able to read from stdin and output tab delimited streams. implement a mapper and if needed, a reducer (and if relevant, configure that as the combiner).

Answer (score 0):

I've added MapReduce implementation using Hadoop on Github with few test cases here: https://github.com/sauravsahu02/MapReduceUsingScala.
Hope that helps. Note that the application is already tested.